# How to conduct a power analysis for a multivariate regression?

Tags: effect-size, statistical-power, multivariate-regression

I'm having a really hard time finding resources on power analyses for multivariate regression. (To quickly provide the details: I have seven predictors and two continuous outcome measures. The two outcome measures are two measures of the same construct. Four of the predictors are of interest, three are in there as controls. These four  predictors of interest are measures of the same construct.)

In my case, I have no previous literature to go on; I am assuming a small effect size (i.e., f2 = .02) relating the predictor and outcome constructs.

I would like to know the power at a given sample size. As far as I can tell G*Power can't do a power analysis for multivariate regression. Is there something I do to its estimate of a univariate regression to adjust it? Is there another way to answer this question?

Comment: The first issue to address, it would seem, is how to define an effect size for a multivariate outcome.  Do you have one in mind?